# Diferença estilo :hover firefox x chrome

Tags: css, css3

Tenho o seguinte CSS

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder, 
:-moz-placeholder, 
::-moz-placeholder, 
:-ms-input-placeholder {
 color: rgb(150,150,150);
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder:hover, 
:-moz-placeholder:hover,  
::-moz-placeholder:hover, 
:-ms-input-placeholder:hover {
 color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

O

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder, 
:-moz-placeholder, 
::-moz-placeholder, 
:-ms-input-placeholder {
 color: rgb(150,150,150);
}
```

funciona em todos os navegadores que testei, mas o

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder:hover, 
:-moz-placeholder:hover,  
::-moz-placeholder:hover, 
:-ms-input-placeholder:hover {
 color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

Só funciona no firefox.

Onde está o erro?

Obs.: já tentei com **:focus**, também não funcionou

Answer (score 1):

Aqui funciona com focus

```css
:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #ff0000; };
:focus:-moz-placeholder { color: #ff0000; };
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="texto placeholder"/>
```

Comment: O problema é que eu estava fazendo uma linha debaixo da outra. Por isso não deu certo. Quando coloquei todas debaixo da mesma linha funcionou.

Comment: @CarlosRocha ops, não entendi.

Comment: :focus::-webkit-input-placeholder, :focus:-moz-placeholder {..}